# SSRS make a conditional format on the column

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

In a SSRS matrix report I'm trying to make a conditional format on the 'Total' column
By checking one of the columns for a specific value,

For example:
In case in one of the Groups (Toys, Clothing, Food), the revenue for a certain day is zero then I want to display the total's values in red
See – 05/01/2015 and 'Clothing' then the 'Total' of this day will be in red.

[image]

Any idea how to do it

Thanks for your respond

Comment: Have you looked at [Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx?)

Answer (score 2):

For each data cell of your table (or matrix) you will have to set an expression on the font color (general tab under text box properties):
[image]

*Now I am making assumptions of what your dataset/columns are called so you will have to translate those appropriately to your report setup.*

For the `Revenue` and `Quantity` cells within each category the expression will be something similar to:

`==IIF(Fields!ToysRevenue.Value <= 0,"Red","Black")`

The expression for your `Total Revenue` and `Total Quantity` are a bit more lengthy since you have to check each `Revenue` value for each category, but it should look something like:

```
==IIF(Fields!ToysRevenue.Value <= 0 Or
Fields!ClothingRevenue.Value <= 0 Or
Fields!FoodRevenue.Value <= 0, "Red","Black")
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your reply, the categories can be changed (add or remove)  

So I need it to be a dynamic formula

Comment: @itzikPaz Why does your question make no mention of that requirement? To do that will require code at the report level. How do you plan on handling that in the column headers?

Comment: the update is done automatically by the query, 
another row in this case become to additional column
for example if I go into the food market than I have another row with category of Food...

Comment: Well that I know of there is no way of handling that requirement within a BIDS developed report. If you want to check the value of a cell in a matrix table you have to know the name of the cell or dataset value. So if the ccell is dynamically controlled already it would be done within that control I guess.